# How weblogic hash the console user name and password

Tags: weblogic12c, string-hashing

I would like to know the way weblogic hash the user name and password of it's console.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you want to know how weblogic encrypts passwords look at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13749/utils.htm#ADMRF142 and http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/08/weblogic-using-encrypted-passwords.html or something else?

Comment: The link has been very helpful I didn't get the mechanism of encryption but I get the service location, thanks alot.